# How to get x:name of an element for tapped gesture

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to get the xmal of my element name ("GridCarreDroiteBasPleinImage")  but I cannot see how

```
      <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="GridCarreDroiteBasPlein">                                 
           <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image x:Name="GridCarreDroiteBasPleinImage" Source="" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">    
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                              <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImageNewsTapped"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>    
                </Image>   
           </AbsoluteLayout >
      </StackLayout>
```

Here the function I have tried to create:

```cs
    void OnImageNewsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {           
         var imageSender = (Image)sender;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the name or what do you want to do?

Comment: Why you need to get the x:name since it is accessible directly from code behind

Comment: because I have many images that call the same function so I would like to get the name of image that called the function

Comment: could't you get the name by `imageSender.Name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ClassId instead of x:Name to identify the Image on which you have tapped.

```
<Image ClassId="GridCarreDroiteBasPleinImage"
              Clicked="OnImageNewsTapped"/>
```

Your code behind becomes:-

```
private void OnImageNewsTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button) sender;
            var classId = button.ClassId;
        }
```